# VSCode: Quick open using directory path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know in VSCode you can use `Ctrl+P` to quick open a file, though it only seems to work for file names. That's not really useful for large python projects when every directory has `__init__.py` files. Is there any way I can quick open files by typing in `directory/__init__.py` to target files more specifically? Sublime Text includes this functionality so it seems strange that VSCode would exclude this.

Comment: This can be done exactly how you described with `ctrl+p`

Comment: only filenames are working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Seems the parent folder names are excluded. For example, if I add a folder named `directory` to the project, I can't search using `directory/folder/filename`, but only `folder/filename`. Still not very useful multiple directories in project with similar file structures.